Generated empty mock file - (Cuckoo mocking framework)
I have created a project for unit testing I have used Cuckoo mocking framework for generating mocks.
With Cuckoo Version: 2.0.8, Mocks.swift is being generated but is empty.
No Error generated, unable to identify the cause of the issue.
Project Repo:
https://github.com/ubitCloud/CuckooP2
Cuckoo Framework:
https://github.com/Brightify/Cuckoo
Cuckoofile.toml
output = "./CuckooP2Tests/GeneratedMocks/Mocks.swift"

[modules.xcworkspace]
testable = true
files = [
  "./CuckooP2/CommentList/Service/CommentViewService.swift",
  # Add other files if needed
]

Run Script
# Skip for indexing
if [ $ACTION == "indexbuild" ]; then
  exit 0
fi

# Skip for preview builds
if [ "${ENABLE_PREVIEWS}" = "YES" ]; then
  exit 0
fi

CONFIG_FILE="$PROJECT_DIR/Cuckoofile.toml"

echo 'Building generator.'
"$PODS_ROOT"/Cuckoo/build_generator

echo 'Generating mocks.'
"$PODS_ROOT"/Cuckoo/Generator/bin/cuckoonator --configuration "$CONFIG_FILE" --verbose


Added path of the input files to the "Input Files" section of the build phase.
/Users/Developer/Downloads/CuckooPractice/CuckooP2/CuckooP2/CommentList/Service/CommentViewService.swift
Added path of the output file to the "Output Files" section of the build phase.
/Users/Developer/Downloads/CuckooPractice/CuckooP2/CuckooP2Tests/GeneratedMocks/Mocks.swift
I want to mock this class "CommentViewModel.swift" then use mock class in unit testing.
Thank you so much for you time and consideration. 

I have successfully generated the mocks with Cuckoo 2.0.8.

I have updated the GitHub repo with the correct cuckoofile.toml and runscript.
